# How to set zoom in to marker using ng click from service

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic google maps app in factory.js. I want to be able to call ng click from UI and have it zoom in to a marker. Sorry for my bad language I am new to ionic and angular.

i have this marker

```
carevandymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(carsarray[1][1],  carsarray[1][2]),
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: evandyimage
                    }); 


return { sayHello: function () {
  console.log(carevandymarker);
  },
```

and a controller

```
$scope.click = function (){
 console.log('jjjjjjj')
 GoogleMaps.sayHello();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't sound like a difficult task;  can you show some of the code of what you have tried?

Comment: i want to panTo this marker using ng click

Answer (score 0):

If you are centering onto the marker when marker clicked:

```
carevandymarker.addListener('click', function() {
    <your-map>.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

or if you are centering to marker when anything else is clicked:

```
$scope.click = function (marker){

    <your-map>.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

    // console.log('jjjjjjj')
    // GoogleMaps.sayHello();
}
```

**Make sure you are somehow referencing that marker, either by passing it in as a parameter or the marker is in global scope.**

Reference: [Marker click](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)